# Difference in table formatting

Tags: tables, alignment

So I'm creating handouts for my class, and I've noticed an inconsistency with how the tables are rendering. I don't think there's a difference between how I've written each table, so I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure how what's going on.

I much prefer the look of the first table, and would like to format the second one to match. However, even after rerunning the compiler I have the same issue.
Here are screenshots I took after compilation:

[image: first table]

which looks perfect to me, but this

[image: second table]

looks gross.

Here is my latex code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{{./images}}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}

Let's examine numerically what happens:\\

\begin{multicols}{2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
$x$ & $f(x)$\\
\hline
$0$ & $-1$ \\
$-0.5$ & $-1.5$\\
$-0.75$ & $-1.75$\\
$-0.825$ & $-1.825$
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
$x$ & $f(x)$\\
\hline
$-2$ & $-3$ \\
$-1.5$ & $-2.5$\\
$-1.25$ & $-2.25$\\
$-1.125$ & $-2.125$
\end{tabular}

\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
$\theta$ & $\sin\theta /\theta$ \\
\hline
$-1.0$ & $0.8415$\\
$-0.1$ & $0.9983$\\
$-0.01$ & $0.9998$
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
$\theta$ & $\sin\theta /\theta$ \\
\hline
$1.0$ & $0.8415$\\
$0.1$ & $0.9983$\\
$0.01$ & $0.9998$
\end{tabular}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Would you please make your code compilable (by adding at least the document class)? Besides: of course a table looks different when all entries in a column have the same length instead of an increasing length.

Comment: @C.Peters edited for that

Comment: I wouldn't use `c` for numeric columns it would look better aligned on the decimal points `S` from `siunitx` or `D` from `dcolumn`

Comment: unrelated but latex does warn you about the mis-placed `\\ ` here `....happens:\\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give an alternative solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. You don't need to use `multicols` environment, but it is better to use `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\begin{document}

Let's examine numerically what happens:

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  Q[si={table-format=-1.3},c,4em]
  Q[si={table-format=-1.3},c,4em]
  c
  Q[si={table-format=-1.3},c,4em]
  Q[si={table-format=-1.3},c,4em]
}
{{{$x$}}} & {{{$f(x)$}}} &  & {{{$x$}}} & {{{$f(x)$}}} \\
\cline{1-2,4-5}
 0     & -1     &  & -2      & -3     \\
-0.5   & -1.5   &  & -1.5    & -2.5   \\
-0.75  & -1.75  &  & -1.25   & -2.25  \\
-0.825 & -1.825 &  & -1.125  & -2.125
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  Q[si={table-format=-1.2},c,4em]
  Q[si={table-format=1.4},c,4em]
  c
  Q[si={table-format=1.2},c,4em]
  Q[si={table-format=1.4},c,4em]
}
{{{$\theta$}}} & {{{$\sin\theta/\theta$}}} &  & {{{$\theta$}}} & {{{$\sin\theta/\theta$}}} \\
\cline{1-2,4-5}
-1.0  & 0.8415 &  & 1.0  & 0.8415 \\
-0.1  & 0.9983 &  & 0.1  & 0.9983 \\
-0.01 & 0.9998 &  & 0.01 & 0.9998
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! (+1). For example, that in my document I use `siunitx` package for writing quantities, etc. and for this reason in preamble I load `siunitx` package. Is then still necessary to load `\UseTblrLibrary{sinuntx}` for use it in `tabularray` tables or this library can cover other needs for `siunitx` package in document?

Comment: Yes, you still need. Without `\UseTblrLibrary{sinuntx}` you can not use `S` column inside `tblr`.

Comment: Are this means, that in case, that in case when  in text I use `siunitx` elements ar `\units{...}`, `\qty{...}{...}` the preamble should be: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{siunitx}` ?

Comment: `\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}` will load `siunitx` package for you. In fact, `siunitx` library depends on `siunitx` package.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now is clear!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Key is to define `\columnsep`. I marked changes in 3 lines with `% <<==`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{{./images}}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}

Let's examine numerically what happens:\\
\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm} % <<==
\begin{multicols}{2}[Title 1, if you need it]   % <<==
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
        $x$ & $f(x)$\\
        \hline
        $0$ & $-1$ \\
        $-0.5$ & $-1.5$\\
        $-0.75$ & $-1.75$\\
        $-0.825$ & $-1.825$
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
        $x$ & $f(x)$\\
        \hline
        $-2$ & $-3$ \\
        $-1.5$ & $-2.5$\\
        $-1.25$ & $-2.25$\\
        $-1.125$ & $-2.125$
    \end{tabular}

\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}[Title 2, if you need it]   % <<==
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
        $\theta$ & $\sin\theta /\theta$ \\
        \hline
        $-1.0$ & $0.8415$\\
        $-0.1$ & $0.9983$\\
        $-0.01$ & $0.9998$
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
        $\theta$ & $\sin\theta /\theta$ \\
        \hline
        $1.0$ & $0.8415$\\
        $0.1$ & $0.9983$\\
        $0.01$ & $0.9998$
    \end{tabular}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image]